# PJSIP - Creating an Objective C Wrapper

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip

I'm attempting to make a simple objective C wrapper by exposing the high level C/C++ API. For a proof of concept, I've implemented the simple SIP UA example given at

http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/simple_pjsua.c

I can get as far as the creating the SIP user account (pjsua_acc_add function below)

```
- (void) registerWithSipServer {

    /* Register to SIP server by creating SIP account. */
    pjsua_acc_config a_cfg;
    pjsua_acc_id acc_id;
    pj_status_t status;


    pjsua_acc_config_default(&a_cfg);
    a_cfg.id = pj_str("sip:" SIP_USER "@" SIP_DOMAIN);
    a_cfg.reg_uri = pj_str("sip:" SIP_DOMAIN);
    a_cfg.cred_count = 1;
    a_cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str(SIP_DOMAIN);
    a_cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
    a_cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(SIP_USER);
    a_cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
    a_cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(SIP_PASSWD);

    status = pjsua_acc_add(&a_cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to start PJSUA");
    }


}
```

but when I try and add it, I get an assertion

> 11:59:07.083       endpoint  ..Request msg REGISTER/cseq=1665
>   (tdta0xbb15200) created. Assertion failed: (mod_stateful_util.id !=
>   -1), function pjsip_endpt_send_request, file ../src/pjsip/sip_util_statefull.c, line 99.

Tracking that down line 99 in sip_util_statefull.c we get the function

```
PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(mod_stateful_util.id != -1, PJ_EINVALIDOP);
```

I've tried to figure out why this fails but have so far come unstuck. Anybody else attempted this?

Comment: You can have a look at other ObjC wrappers for PJSIP here: https://github.com/chakrit/gossip and here: https://github.com/eofster/Telephone - I use the AKSIP wrapper in a popular VoIP app, so I can say it works pretty well.